# How to validate Service Account based authentication in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How to validate Dataflow Java code using Google Service Account?

Currently we are passing user credential to select/validate the Google project for executing Dataflow runner. Instead we need to validate the Dataflow code with Service Account.

It would be good if some one share the Java code to validate the Dataflow Job with Service Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the service account to communicate to Google Cloud all you have to do is to download the JSON file that contains your service account key and change the environment variable of the system to:

For Linux/MacOS:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"
```

For Windows:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

You can get this key from the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?_ga=2.51628207.-762591278.1543924925), select the Service Account you require, select JSON type and then click on create. You now have the JSON file containing your key on your machine.

You then run the job with:

```
--serviceAccount=service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This flag runs with the service account mail. You can get the service account mail from the IAM panel of the Google Console. Also, remember to give the service account the appropriated roles and [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control).

To change the name of the job, you can use `--jobName=[your_job_name]` in order to give an specific name. If you are running the example from the 
[Quickstart Using Java and Apache Maven](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven?hl=hu) documentation, then your job name is going to use part of your username as default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be good if you share any sample code to validate the Dataflow using this Service Account Json file.

Comment: As the Quickstart [https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven] stated, once you run `mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java` with the appropriate flags and values,  `Pdataflow` will get the key from the environment variable that you have defined before.

Comment: Tried to run the Dataflow Job with below scenarios(as you suggested), but still Dataflow starts with my name instead of Service Account.
1) Creating Environment variable with the name "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"  and Path as value.
2) Used "setGcpCredential" in the Pipelineoptions, by passing Google Credentials.
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("[path]\\key.json")).createScoped(SCOPES);  dfOptions.setGcpCredential(credentials); 
Could you please guide me to run the Dataflow with Service Account, instead of my name.

Comment: Can you run: `gcloud auth list`? Check which is the active account. Are you using the Cloud Shell ?

Comment: When I run "gcloud auth list" command, I can see two accounts. 1. Service account 2. my account. I just set service account in my gcloud by running command "gcloud config set account <serviceaccount>". Still Dataflow starts with my name instead of Service Account.However I can see the Service Account name in Dataflow Jobs -> Job Summary -> Pipeline Options section. Also the Job name has my name instead of service account name. Could you suggest any further ideas to run the Dataflow Job name with Service Account. I didnt used Cloud Shell... Tried to run maven command from my Windows laptop.

Comment: The Service account has proper roles and permissions. Also, noted that as per the Migration documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/migrate-java-1-to-2?hl=hu#individual_api_changes) , GcpOptions:  ServiceAccountName, ServiceAccountKeyFile has been removed from version 1.x and in 2.x version requested us to use GoogleCredentials instead. My Dataflow project has version 2.x and I tried to run the dataflow job with GoogleCredentials but still Dataflow starts with my name. Could you suggest any further ideas to run the Dataflow Job name with Service Account.

Comment: Yes, you are right on `ServiceAccountKeyFile` and `ServiceAccountName`. But, `--serviceAccount` is different and is not deprecated. Now, the job name is an arbitrary name that you assign to the job. It has nothing to do with the service account that you are using. To change the **name of the job** you can use ` --jobName=your_job_name` . As I see you were able to see the Service Account been used on the Job Summary, then I don't think there is a problem with the Service Account.

Comment: If we can see the Service Account email in Job Summary then we can confirm that the Dataflow starts with Service Account instead of User Account. Perfect. Thanks for your feedback and Thanks for your help.